# apache2-api-20120211 - How do I install it? No installation candidate

Tags: apache-2.2, packages

Cloudflare module depends on apache2-api-20120211 but there is no installation candidate for it.

What is apache2-api package [virtual package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/652326/whats-a-virtual-package) for? There is no information anywhere regarding this except that apache2-bin provides it on releases [Trusty (14.04) and above](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/apache2-api-20120211)? Also there is a PPA for [Saucy i386 (13.04) in Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/saucy/i386/apache2-bin/2.4.4-6ubuntu2).

How should I deal with this for Precise (12.04)?  Any thoughts?

I could just extract the deb file and modify control file of the `clouldflare package` and remove `apache2-api-20120211` from Depends, rebuild and install. I'm not sure if that would break anything. Even if it doesn't break anything, next-time there is an update from cloulflare, I'll have to repackage it all over again.

Comment: Why do you want to install it, if you don't know what it is for? Do you have components/programs that depend on the package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 1.3.6 depends on `apache2.2-common` OR `apache2-api-20120211` where as the newer ones only depend on `apache2-api-20120211`. They should rebuild the package.

```
libapache2-mod-cloudflare_1.3.1_amd64.deb - DEBIAN/control file
Depends: apache2, apache2.2-common | apache2-api-20120211, libc6 (>= 2.4)


libapache2-mod-cloudflare_2016.10.0-1_amd64.deb - DEBIAN/control file
Depends: apache2, apache2-api-20120211, libc6 (>= 2.4)
```